# Order of menu changes when I float right

Tags: html, css

I am floating my menus to be on the right hand side of the footer, however, I notice the order of the menu has changed. I want the order to remain the same whilst I float right. Is this possible and how to resolve?

```
<aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
  <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
  <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
<aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
  <h5 class="widget_title">ABOUT</h5>
  <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79760"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Our Story</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7961"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7958"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>

    footer [id*=nav_menu] {
    float:right;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just order them the other way round (what comes first will float furthest right, then the next one won't be quite so right etc).

However, I note that in your example code you have two elements with the same id, this is not correct HTML. You could use a class instead, or different ids - if they contain the same substring the CSS will work with a wild card.